# What is the difference between @Nonnull and Objects.requireNonNull

Tags: java

What is the difference between following two code snippets.

```
public Integer getId(@Nonnull SomeObject obj){  
    // do some stuff
    return id;
}

public Integer getId(SomeObject obj){   
    Objects.requireNonNull(SomeObject, "SomeObject is null");
    // do some stuff
    return id;
}
```

What are the significant differences between them. And what is the correct way to do the null-check in these situations.

Comment: One out of multiple aspects: In contrast to Objects.requireNonNull the annotation does not necessarily do anything if it is not considered.

Comment: `@Nonnull` is telling the compiler that the given argument should not be `null`, whereas `requireNonNull` checks if the given object is `null`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two are complementary: `@Nonnull` annotation documents the fact that `obj` must be non-null, while `Objects.requireNonNull` call ensures that `obj` is non-null at run-time.

You should combine the two, like this:

```
public Integer getId(@Nonnull SomeObject obj){   
    Objects.requireNonNull(SomeObject, "SomeObject is null");
    // do some stuff
    return id;
}
```

Relevant documentation on `@Nonnull` can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-8s-new-type-annotations):

> **Optional Type Annotations are not a substitute for runtime validation**
>
> Before Type Annotations, the primary location for describing things like nullability or ranges was in the javadoc. With Type annotations, this communication comes into the bytecode in a way for compile-time verification.
>
> Your code should still perform runtime validation.

Comment: God what I would do for a proper non-nullable reference type (that you could later use to reference an Option/Optional/Maybe type)

Comment: @Alexander - Would you use Kotlin?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth If I had to target the JVM and was given the choice, yeah. But so many companies are stuck on Java.

Comment: I noticed the Nonnull interface in javax.annotation has the `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`. Anyone know what does that mean ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, So the Objects.requireNonNull is not needed when we use https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull

Comment: @prime The article that you linked is specific to the library they develop and code that it generates for you.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yeah, in that case that library will take care of the run time validation I think.

Comment: if you are using Spring and you combine `@NotNull` with spring `@Validate` annotation at the class level, spring will take care of the validation at the runtime also.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that in the first case it's a hint for a compiler and IDE that the argument should not be null, so when you write `getId(null)`you'll get an error. But someone may pass `null` value in runtime.

As for the second case, it's a kind of defensive programming, when you fail-fast with a precondition that the argument should not be `null`.

Comment: @prime yes, at runtime when null value is passed as an argument and you invoke methods of that object.

Answer (score 7):

One of these is an annotation which implements [JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305), but is meant more for static analysis as opposed to a runtime guard.  As I recall it, JSR-305 is a good idea in principle and a lot of things actually leverage it in some way, but it loses a lot of its bark when its utility only ever comes in the form of static analysis.

Case in point:  your IDE can leverage this to warn you of situations in which you're passing something you shouldn't, but it can't prevent you from passing `null` into this method when you compile.

`Objects.requireNonNull` is a **runtime enforcement** that whatever it's passed will be a non-null reference.  The compiler can't enforce this either, but at runtime should you receive a null value, you will get a `NullPointerException` upon executing that line of code.

In terms of correctness, using `Objects.requireNonNull` is a good idea, but that depends on what your obligation is when running the application.  If you ***must*** fail on a null value, then using that is fine as it will generate a runtime exception to deal with.  If you ***can't*** fail on a null value, then using an `if` check instead would be better.